# Как организовать кеширование аватар

Tags: веб-сервер, браузер, кэширование

На сайте регистрируются пользователи, закачивают свои фотки, пишут посты. В каждом посте хранится id пользователя, и ссылка на фото автора генерируется как

```
http://сайт.ру/user/**<userid>**/photo.png
```

Но здесь беда - фотки авторов конечно же, кешируются браузером. И при смене чьего-либо фото, оно конечно же, не обновится.

Вопрос в следующем - как эти вещи сделать "по уму", чтобы фотки были актуальными?
Какой существует грамотный подход для решения этого вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, до меня дошло!

1. Заведу поле `user.lastupdate` - буду фиксировать момент последних изменений профиля.
2. При закачке новой аватарки менять этот `lasupdate = now()`
3. При выдаче постов пользователя вместе с id автора буду выдавать и `user.lastupdate`
4. url аватарки буду генерировать как `/user/<user.id>/photo.png?<user.lastupdate>`